# Doing an update on MySQL in one statement

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make this SQL (MySQL) to update a third table, based on the data form two previous ones.
Reason I need it, is we are doing some user testing, and since I am the only one with access to the DB, I need some way to make changes quick. those changes are requested form front end developers. I surely can go via email, and find out the user_account and then find the third table, but it would be ideal they send me this query and I just run it. Database is test one, so even with bad queries no harm done.

In short. User table is connected to user_account via user_id. And the hird table is connected via user_account_id.

I have tried this SQL, but it executes with no results (0 rows affected).

```
SET @id1 = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = 'someemail@aaa.com');
SET @id2 = (SELECT id FROM user_accounts WHERE user_id = @id1);
UPDATE user_product_status AS ups
SET access_starts_at = '2022-04-03 08:52:58'
WHERE ups.user_account_id = @id2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to [`UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) one or more [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)-ed tables. The query is:

```
UPDATE user_product_status ups
INNER JOIN user_accounts ua ON ups.user_account_id = ua.id
INNER JOIN users u ON ua.user_id = u.id
SET ups.access_starts_at = '2022-04-03 08:52:58'
WHERE u.email = 'someemail@aaa.com'
```

You can change this query into a `SELECT` query to check what rows will be updated:

```
SELECT * FROM user_product_status ups
INNER JOIN user_accounts ua ON ups.user_account_id = ua.id
INNER JOIN users u ON ua.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.email = 'someemail@aaa.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using a join for your query

```
UPDATE user_product_status AS ups
JOIN user_accounts ac ON ac.user_id = ups.user_account_id
JOIN users u ON u.id = ac.user_id
SET access_starts_at = '2022-04-03 08:52:58'
WHERE u.email = 'someemail@aaa.com'
```

Comment: MySQL Workbench is complaining that UPDATE is not valid input at this position.

Comment: @VedranMaricevic. are you using some kind of stored procedure ?

Comment: No Stored Procedure. Just a regular SQL console inside the MySQL workbench.

Comment: @VedranMaricevic. can you provide your table definitions and with relevant data set on http://sqlfiddle.com/ ?

Comment: Here are the table definitions. I made them much smaller, as it contains non relevant structures: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a17e87

Comment: @VedranMaricevic. it works fine in fiddle see updated fiddle demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f294a2/1 ?

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I cant get it to work for some reason. It does nothing. Good thing to know that the query is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE user_product_status
SET access_starts_at = '2022-04-03 08:52:58'
from user_product_status ups
JOIN user_accounts ac ON ac.user_id = ups.user_account_id
JOIN users u ON u.id = ac.user_id
WHERE u.email = 'someemail@aaa.com'
```

Comment: The [`UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) statement does not contain a `FROM` clause.